# How do you modify the default to accept Y or N not just Y in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, default

I'm trying to modify the default in a column on an existing table but it is not working. I have researched in other sites but it's not working.

```
ALTER TABLE STOREREPS
MODIFY (COMM DEFAULT ('Y', 'N'));
```

where my default is set to just `Y`.

I am using Oracle 11g SQL Developer.

Comment: In future, please add which DBMS you are using into your question, preferably from the start, but at least when prompted. I prefer to see it in both the tags and in the body of the question, but at least include it in the tags.  Although there is an SQL standard, no DBMS implements 100% of the standard, and there are often variants on the syntax. Frequently, this is because the DBMS implemented the feature before it was standardized, and the standard syntax deviated from the prior implementation, but backwards compatibility means that the developers are stuck with their non-standard syntax.

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can only have one default value.  The default value is used when you INSERT a row into the table and don't specify a value for the column.  You can add a CHECK constraint to ensure that only `'Y'` or `'N'` is allowed, though; that is probably what you are seeking.

Subject to variations per DBMS (now identified as Oracle), you could write something [like](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php):

```
ALTER TABLE STOREREPS
    MODIFY (COMM DEFAULT 'Y'),
    ADD CONSTRAINT check_comm_y_n CHECK (COMM IN ('Y', 'N'));
```

In a CREATE TABLE statement, that might be:

```
CREATE TABLE StoreReps
(
    …
    Comm CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y'
         CONSTRAINT check_comm_y_n CHECK (Comm IN ('Y', 'N')),
    …
);
```

but the exact syntax varies by DBMS.

Comment: Thanks you for help people, @Jonathan since i already set the default the MODIFY part does not work.  Thank you for you help. It helped out a lot.

Comment: I wondered about that, hence the prevarication.  At least the clauses are largely independent, so it isn't hard to omit the MODIFY and just use the ADD CONSTRAINT.